# Modifying Wordpress Admin

Tags: wordpress

When you are in the Wordpress back end and you hover over 'Settings', and click 'General', a page comes up with, of course, the general settings for the site.  The labels for each input field are as follows: Site Title, Tagline, Wordpress address (URL), Site address (URL), etc.

I'm looking to add a function to my functions.php for a theme that will allow me to change these labels.

Is this even possible? Or do I just have to hard code it in?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom [translation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress), or just hook into Wordpress's translation functions (using the [`gettext`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) filter) and supply your own translations:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'my_gettext', 10, 3);

function my_gettext($translation, $text, $domain) {
  if ($text == 'Site Title') {
    $translation = 'Foo Bar';
  }
  return $translation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the *value* of the labels, you could write a function that directly updates the setting in wp_options table.
If you want to change the labels, the solution posted by Richard M will work.